# Jenkins pipeline with pure Java code producing compilation issues

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline as shown below. The purpose of this pipeline is to help debug some java network issue in a mutual TLS handshake. I have disabled the `Use Groovy Sandbox` checkbox. I have very little background in groovy syntax but I have good background in Java.

```
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.*;

pipeline {
    agent {label "aws"}
    
    stages {
        stage('First Stage') {
            steps {
                System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this pipeline I get the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 13: Expected a symbol @ line 13, column 17.
                   System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
```

Why do I see compilation errors here? Does groovy have a different way of importing packages/classes?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured it out I think. Looks like the pipeline is declarative while the `System.setProperty..` is a scripted step. So wrapping it in a `script` closure fixed it:

```
steps {
    script {
      System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
    }
}
```